# How to separate Stata macro `varlist' with commas for using in mi( ) and inlist( )?

Tags: stata, stata-macros

I want to store a list of variables in a macro and then call that macro inside a `mi()` statement. The original application is for a programme that uses data I cannot bring online for secrecy reasons, and which will include the following statement:

```
generate u = cond(mi(`vars'),., runiform(0,1))
```

The issue being that `mi()` requires comma separated variable names but `vars` is delimited by spaces.

I use the `auto` dataset and `mark` to illustrate my problem:

```
sysuse auto
local myvars foreign price
mark missing if mi(`myvars')
```

In this example, `mi()` asks for arguments separated by commas, Stata stops and complains that it cannot find a `foreignprice` variable. Is there a utility function that will insert the commas between the macro elements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A direct answer to the question as set is to use the macro extended function `subinstr` to change spaces to commas:

```
sysuse auto
local myvars foreign price
local myvars : subinstr local myvars " " ",", all 
mark missing if mi(`myvars')
```

If the aim is to create a marker variable that marks observations with any values missing on specified variables, then there are other alternative ways, most of which don't need any fiddling with separators in a list. This doesn't purport to be a complete set.

A1.

```
 regress foreign price 
 gen missing = !e(sample)
```

A2.

```
 egen missing = rowmiss(foreign price) 
 replace missing = missing > 0
```

A3.

```
 local myvars foreign price 
 local myvars : subinstr local myvars " " ",", all 
 gen missing = missing(`myvars')
```

A4.

```
 gen missing = 0 
 quietly foreach v in foreign price { 
     replace missing = 1 if missing(`v') 
 }
```

A5.

```
 mark missing 
 markout missing foreign price 
 replace missing = !missing
```

EDIT In the edited question there is reference to this within a program:

```
 generate u = cond(mi(`vars'),., runiform(0,1))
```

I wouldn't do that, even with the macro edited to include commas too, although any issue is more one of personal taste.

```
 marksample touse 
 markout `vars' 
 generate u = runiform(0,1) if `touse'
```

It's likely that the indicator variable so produced is needed, or at least useful, somewhere else in the same program.

Comment: Hi. That does the job. I used mark as the example because it was easier to do, but I intend to use it as a condition inside a programme instead of with mark.

Comment: Good, but if your real question is different you need to tell us what it is.

Comment: Edited the question to clarify the intended application.